# How to do .Net Web Api versioning/routing for an app client?

Tags: asp.net, api, asp.net-web-api, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

So there are several parts to this question.
The 2 example endpoints (in simplest form):

```
user/{id}/profile
movie/{id}/info
```

I expect to create 2 controllers (UserController & MovieController).

> 1. How do I implement a view area before controller name?

Both of these are what I would consider a **view**. Therefore I would like to append a "view" in the url before the controller, as both controllers ONLY supply **views**. I later expect to also have a user controller in a different place that does NOT return **views**.
However, **ALL** my endpoints should start with */api/*.

i.e. I want this:

```
api/view/user/{id}/profile
api/view/movie/{id}/info
```

But how do I register an area (**/view/**) while using "custom routing" (i.e.: httpConfiguration.MapHttpAttributeRoutes())? Any examples of this I couldn't find?

> 2. Where should I put versioning?

The client is an app, and will require versioning, so that we can make changes to the methods without breaking old versions of the app.

We are unsure where it would be best to place the versioning, and how the placement affects the development of new versions (if it does so at all?).

Possibilities:

```
1. api/v1/view/user/{id}/profile
2. api/view/v1/user/{id}/profile
3. api/view/user/{id}/profile/v1
```

1. version the whole API. This would upgrade the whole API to a new version, even if we only required a single method/endpoint to make an app-breaking change. 
   Are there **any** advantages to this that I am not seeing?
2. version the area. Same as above, just slightly fewer controllers affected.
3. version the method. Seems like the simplest, as only the single changed method is affected. But the url is very ugly.

Does anyone have an example of versioning in an MVC or Web Api structure that doesn't upgrade the whole API, but still keeps a somewhat nice structure in their URLs?

Comment: Why not just use [aspnet-api-versioning](https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning)?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning as suggested by NightOwl888.

1.

Made my 2 controllers extend another controller with a const field that defined the routeprefix that they should share:

```
protected const string RoutePrefix = "api/view/v{version:apiVersion}";
...
[RoutePrefix(RoutePrefix + "/user")]
```

2.

The placement of the **/v1/** doesn't matter with this Library. And allowed for either updating the controller or individuals methods, as seen fit per case basis.